# How to build line chart in power bi for temperature vs date

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-datasource

I have table storage as data source. Data is IoT data and every 10 seconds I get new row with timestamp.

I can succesfully connect with Power BI Desktop. I have changed data type as Date/Time. Column name is Timestamp and values is in format of "10/12/2016 13:08:30". Another column is temperature in decimal format like "23.0".

Now how to make line chart where I can see how temperature get changing over time? **I would like to see entire last month data in a graph and then can drill down to week/day/hour wise**?

I understand and Timestamp is Axis and Temperature is Value, but I get values for every 10 seconds.

[image]

Comment: Use the line chart visualization and add `Timestamp` to the Axis and `Temperature` to the Values.

Comment: I did same but it takes count of values per category instead of just value

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of your PowerBI window?

Comment: i have attached screenshot..

Comment: Can you change the quick measure to a Max or Average or is your `TempFreezer` formatted as text?

Comment: Thank you Alexis for your suggestion.after changing the TempFreezer  from text datatype to decimal.it works.it saves me time and could you also provide me suggestions how to drill down from days to weeks ,and hours